# DocuSign upload documents

Tags: docusignapi

I want to upload a document to DocuSign with DocuSign API and I'm using an example that uploads a document and sends email to the recipient but I can't upload only the document.

This is the example: http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument

Do you know if I can upload the document to my DocuSign account without sending an email? And to another user account  using my credentials?

Answer (score 1):

If you set **status** to "created" in the API request (instead of setting it to "sent" as the example code does), then this will result in the creation of a "Draft" envelope in DocuSign.  The Draft envelope will contain the document(s) that you uploaded with your 'create Envelope' API request, but no email(s) will be sent to recipient(s), because the Envelope is just a draft -- i.e., it hasn't been sent yet (email(s) won't be sent until the Envelope is sent).

It is possible to create a Draft envelope in another user's account, by using "Send On Behalf Of" functionality.  See **Send On Behalf Of Functionality in the DocuSign REST API** starting on page 16 in the REST API Guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for details about how this works.